# Can I downgrade SSIS packages to run on older version of SQL

Tags: ssis

We have some new SQL 2008 SSIS jobs that were recently developed, mostly to do some simple flat-file loading and targeting a set of tables on a 2008 server.

As it turns out, they may have to run on a SQL 2005 server for both the SSIS and target tables.

Is it possible to *downgrade* the packages somehow, instead of redeveloping them from scratch?

Obviously any 2008 specific SSIS features would disappear; but it would be nice to not start with a blank designer screen.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[SSIS Downgrade](http://ssisctc.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=SSIS%20Downgrade&referringTitle=Home) should do exactly what you need.

Answer (score 2):

A second option would be to run the SSIS packages on ServerA2008 and set the connection managers for your source/destination to be ServerB2005.  No code change required and you should be able to continue using the 2008 features.

One caveat to this approach is it will not work if you use the "SQL Server Destination" component as it requires the package be executed on the same machine as the destination.

Answer (score 0):

It worked for me by going to VS Project->Properties and then change to the appropriate version, say 2012, that you need. The package has converted successfully from VS2015 to run on 2012.